# Django-ckeditor styling

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

There is an option in CONFIG:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        ...
```

But actually I can't even switch to `office2013` theme, I am getting white block only.

Is there any way to enable other themes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-ckeditor is shipped only with the moono skin. you need to download the skin that you want, and put it on your static dir:

`%STATIC_DIR%/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/`

Answer (score 2):

First level: 
     You Must Download CkEditor with office2013 theme.

Second level:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name=_('Title'), blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=50000, verbose_name=_('Message'), blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = { models.TextField: {'widget': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'ckeditor'})}, }

    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor/ckeditor.js',) # The , at the end of this list IS important.
        css = {
            'all': ('ckeditor/contents.css',)
        }

admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was an enormous help.